# Chrome Heap Snapshot - Why it doesn't show all the memory allocated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl, google-chrome-devtools

I'm running some memory usage tests in a WebGL project that I have. If I start the page on Google Chrome and take a heap snapshot on the Profiles tab of Developers Tool, it will say that my page is holding 7.5 MB.

The problem is if I look into Task Manager, the real value that it is using is almost 1 GB! It is expected, since I am really forcing the page to have thousands of objects, but the question is: why Chrome shows to me that I am using only 7.5 MB?

Comment: Chrome's processes are spread out among plugins, tabs, and the main chrome service. What exactly do you want a snapshot of?

Comment: @TheZ What I really want to know is the amount of memory my page is using.

Comment: You should file a bug at http://crbug.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**update**

there was native memory snapshot that was able to show you the native memory graph.
Unfortunately we removed it because it was a fragile piece of code. 
It required nontrivial instrumentation in hundreds of classes and affected the binary size.
I hope we reimplement it later.

**was**

It takes a snapshot of Javascript heap. All your javascript objects use 7.5mb. This size doesn't include images, canvases, audio files, plugin data, etc.

There is a native memory snapshot in DevTools.
It counts non-javascript memory used by the renderer process but this is an experimental feature.

You need to enable DevTools experimental feature in `chrome://flags`, restart the browser, enable Native Memory Profiler experimental feature in DevTools settings panel and reopen DevTools.

After all these steps you will be able to take Native Memory Snapshot in Profiler panel.
Not all the memory chunks in the native memory heap are counted but we are working on that.

Please use the [Canary version of Chrome](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs).
It updates every day and works side-by-side with other versions of Chrome.

If your page eats gigabytes of memory and has big "Other" bar, more than 10%-20%, please drop a mail about that to the [Google Chrome Developer Tools Foums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US&fromgroups#!forum/google-chrome-developer-tools).

Comment: Unfortunately google have removed the native memory snapshot feature from the experimental dev tools.  I don't know why.  But it means that this answer is no longer valid :/

Comment: there was native memory snapshot that was able to show you the native memory graph. Unfortunately we removed it because it was a fragile piece of code. It required nontrivial instrumentation in hundreds of classes and affected the binary size. I hope we reimplement it later.

Comment: Thanks for the update - Looks like I can no longer award the bounty, but have a +1!

Comment: years passed, but Google didin't give us a way to profile native memory

Comment: Is there any way to do this now in 2018? I see that the "Native memory sampling profiler" flag is there in Chrome v69 but after enabling and restarting I still cannot see an option to take a native memory snapshot in the DevTools.

Answer (score -1):

You can still take snapshots under the profile tab and click take head snapshot which gives you in-depth memory usage stats.

Comment: The shapshots just give you a view of the heap.  As the question states, the problem is analysing the memory usage that is shown in the Chrome Task Manager, but which does not show up in the heap.