# Huge difference between memory usage displayed in chrome's task manager and memory timeline

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to profile the memory usage of my application using chrome's memory time line. 
However i am seeing huge difference between the values reported in the time line and the values displayed by the chrome's task manager. When i profiled myweb page on chrome yesterday, the memory usage in the time line is between 11MB to 14 MB. However chrome's task manager is hovering at around 135MB Why is this difference ? If memory usage as displayed in the timeline is correct what's memory that's used by the task manager ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Heap Snapshot - Why it doesn't show all the memory allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318109/chrome-heap-snapshot-why-it-doesnt-show-all-the-memory-allocated)