# JavaScript heap memory is constant, but the browser process private bytes are growing. Where does the memory difference come from?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

I am troubleshooting what appears to be a memory leak in our configuration page. The page is used to change the configuration of our service and also displays health diagnostics. This means that we are querying the service periodically for configuration and instrumentation information (typically we use a query interval of 30sec, but to troubleshoot I am querying at 100ms intervals). We rely on knockoutjs, datajs, jquery and spinjs.

I've found that if I leave the page open overnight at the 100ms query interval that the private bytes for the chrome browser tab grows from about 50MB to 335MB. I have four pages with the issue, but am focused on one during my troubleshooting effort. Using chrome://memory-redirect/ I can see the page (process id 26148) memory.

[image]

However, the JavaScript heap memory appears to be flat over the same period at 3.6MB. Using the heap profiling tools in Chrome it shows that all of my object allocations are garbage collected.

[image]

In the above picture the gray allocations indicate that the objects have been cleaned up by the GC.

[image]

The memory timeline also is constant.

[image]

I also forced two GCs and confirmed that the number of documents, nodes and listeners was constant between the two GCs.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Where is the process memory being used that is not part of the JavaScript heap?
2. Given our JavaScript heap memory is flat, could that extra memory be a memory leak caused by our JavaScript code?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you have your network tab enabled when the console is open? This will keep a copy of request headers, response headers, body, etc for each request made

Comment: @PaulS. - Are you implying that if opened then the network tab could cause the issue? I did not have the the Chrome dev tools enabled, including the network tab, while running the test that showed the memory usage increase because I was afraid it would use a lot of extra memory and give me false results.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue? We are seeing the same behavior in Chrome 40.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  Running an application that makes a lot of REST calls per second.  Tab memory grows proportionally with the REST calls, but heap size stays about the same.  Chrome 40.

Comment: @CullyLarson - I never got to the exact root cause of this. In the end I took the macro approach and just left the page open for weeks to see what would happen to the process's memory. The memory eventually got cleaned up and did not grow unbounded. It still plateaued too high for my liking (it was a long time ago and I can't remember the exact numbers now), but at least there was a limit.

Comment: @integragreg - See the above comment. It wouldn't let me reply to both of you at once.

Comment: In my case the issue is with an svg/raphael simulation. Similarly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318109/chrome-heap-snapshot-why-it-doesnt-show-all-the-memory-allocated . I still can't seem to find a definitive way to diagnose this.

Answer (score -2):

You are comparing apples and oranges - Garbage collected memory in a sub-heap and whole application memory.

You've used Chrome to inspect the JavaScript heap and found evidence that indicates the JavaScript part of your application is running OK.

You're also using a tool to monitor the global memory usage of Chrome itself. That is all the memory that Chrome is using for any task, including tasks not directly related to your application, but to the functioning of the browser itself.

Perhaps you've found a use case that triggers a memory leak in the Chrome internals?

Or perhaps it isn't a memory leak, but memory fragmentation in the non-garbage collected internal heaps used by Chrome?

According to this [web page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) Chrome is written in a mixture of C, C++, Java, JavaScript and Python. This means we have deterministic memory allocators for C and C++ and three different types of garbage collected heaps for Java, JavaScript and Python. Bad news: Python's handling of integers isn't so kind on memory use when it comes to garbage collection (last time I checked, which was a few years ago, maybe they've improved it).

But I've had Chrome sessions run for weeks without issue. So I do wonder what is happening.

You don't say which OS you are using but if you are using Microsoft Windows then you could use [C++ Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-memory.php) to inspect where each allocation was made (full callstack, how many bytes, etc) while Chrome is running (Launch Chrome from C++ Memory Validator, load your applicaton, let it do it's thing then go to the **Memory** tab and click **Refresh** - it will display all the live allocations that can be tracked - any statically linked heaps won't be trackable as you won't have the symbols to allow them to be hooked). OK, you don't have symbols to make teh callstacks readable but you can still identify allocations happening at the same place. That may give you a clue as to the cause of the leak/fragmentation so that can report this to the Chrome devs for a closer look.

Do you get the same behaviour in Firefox? If you then you could do what I suggest with C++ Memory Validator but do it on a build of Firefox that you've built yourself - you'll have symbols and source and know exactly where the problem is.

Disclaimer. I am the designer of C++ Memory Validator.